# Unable to declare resource_type variable and event status in Terraform for azure resource health alert.showing conflicting error Msg

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

> Trying to add the Event status in Resource health block (not accepting it)

> Tried  adding  the resource_type variable as mentioned in terraform documentation to
> select the resource types to get this alert apply on.but its omitting
> conflicting error msg is

> "criteria.. resource health": conflicts with criteria.o.resource type

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "reshealthalert" {
      name                = "resourceHealthFromMain "
      resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      scopes              = ["/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id}"]
      description         = var.monitor_activity_log_alert_description
      criteria {

    category = var.criteria_resource_health

   # resource_type = "Storage account"


   
    resource_health {
      current = var.current_resource_status
      previous = var.previous_resource_status
     # events = var.resource_health_events
      reason = var.reason_type
      
      #event_status = var.resource_health_events
      
    }   }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.email_alert.id   }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below terraform code.

- Please make sure to give `resource_type` before category and give resourceId
  format of storage account in the form ***`resource_type= "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"`***

***main.tf***

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "reshealthalert" {
      name                = "ka-resource-Health "
      resource_group_name =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      scopes              = ["/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx"]
      description         = "This alert will monitor a specific storage account updates."
      resource_type= "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
      #resource_type = "Storage account"
     
      criteria {

    category = var.criteria_resource_health

    ...

}
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_activity_log_alert#current)